# laravel, get data by id using foreach

Tags: laravel, foreach

how do I fetch the data based on the insurance_id on the companion db? the insurance_id is dependent on another table called "insurances" if that helps. the db is this:

[image]

and the view looks like this:

[image]

here's the view:

```
<table class="table" id="companions_table">
<thead>
   <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date of Birth</th>
        <th>IC No</th>
        <th>Relationship</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

   <tbody>
      @foreach (old('companions', $companions->count() ? $companions : ['']) as $companion)
        <tr id="companion{{ $loop->index }}">
          <td>
                <input type="text" name="companion_name[]" id="companion_name[]" class="form-control" value="{{ old('companion_name', $companion->companion_name) }}" />
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-today-highlight="true" data-date-end-date="0d">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="dob[]" id="dob[]" value="{{ old('dob', $companion->dob) }}">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="ic[]" id="ic[]" class="form-control" value="{{ old('ic', $companion->ic) }}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="relationship[]" id="relationship[]" class="form-control" value="{{ old('relationship', $companion->relationship) }}" />
        </td>
        </tr>
      @endforeach
                <tr id="companion{{ count(old('companions', $companions->count() ? $companions : [''])) }}"></tr>
                    /tbody>
                    </table>
                
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left">+ Add Row</button>
                <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">- Delete Row</button>
            </div>
```

my controller:

```
public function edit(Insurance $insurance)
{
    abort_if(Gate::denies('insurance_edit'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

    $customers = CustomerProfile::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '');

    $products = Product::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '');

    $sales_2s = User::all()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.pleaseSelect'), '');

    $companions = Companion::all();

    $insurance->load('customer', 'product', 'sales_2', 'team', 'companions');

    $approvers = Role::findOrFail(3)->users()->get();

    return view('admin.insurances.edit', compact('customers', 'products', 'sales_2s', 'insurance', 'approvers', 'companions'));
}
```

it keeps fetching all the data on the table, basically disregarding the insurance_id. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the companions are being fetched, regardless of the `insurance_id`, because of the following line:

```php
$companions = Companion::all();
```

If you only want companions with the current `insurance_id`, the quickest way would be to replace the previously mentioned line with:

```php
$companions = Companion::where('insurance_id', $insurance->id)->get();
```

This should work, however the conventional way to handle this relationship in Laravel would be by adding the following function to your `Insurance` model:

```php
use App\Models\Companion; // or wherever your model happens to be located

public function companions()
{
      return $this->hasMany(Companion::class);
}
```

And replacing the line mentioned at the beginning with:

```php
$companions = $insurance->companions;
```

Comment: tried both of your solutions however, I got an error of "Trying to get property 'companion_name' of non-object (0)".

I also tried replacing the code on the view, the error changed to:  "Property [companion_name] does not exist on this collection instance. (0)"

Comment: nevermind, I failed to notice $companions->companion_name should be $companion->companion_name. thank you so much!